# passing values to another method

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nsstring

I am setting the value for the string in the `viewdidload` method and getting the string value in the button action method the app gets crashed. can I know the reason for crashing and how to pass the values to the method.

in .h file

```
NSString *test;
```

in .m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample"];
}

-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"%@", test);
}
```

When I pressed the button the app crashes.

Comment: initialize property in .h file also

Comment: What is the console message when it crashes?

Comment: @RKK i initialize the property in .h file and synthesize in .m file

Comment: @Phillip there is no console msg its empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using this solution, I think this will help you,

Create Property of `test` in `.h` file like this,,

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *test;
```

and `synthesize` it in `.m` file like this,

```
@synthesize test;
```

now use `test` as `self.test` in .m file like this,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    self.test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample"];
}

-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.test);
}
```

Another solution for this is just `retain` that `test` string in `ViewDidLoad` also, I think this will also help you..

Hope this will help you..

Comment: thanks a lot it works we can also use the same thing for others like array, dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to explain it in more detail:

You have a string variable in `.h` file. In view did load you are assigning it as:

```
test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample"];
```

What actually happning in this code is your test is a autoreleased object. When you use this and object without `alloc` and `init` this is autoreleased object and will release memory after the method you occupied it.

For avoiding this situation you can use **@Mehul's solution** by creating property. This is against encapsulation concept. Sometimes you have objects you don't want to access outside of the class or don't want to show with objects. Use following in those conditions:

```
test = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample"] retain]; // or
test = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"sample"];
```

this will keep your string alive till you release it.

There is another way that is not good to use but want to tell you so you can understand it better. Using

```
test = @"sample";
```

If you don't want to append string or use it with format you can assign simple string to you `NSString` object.

using this will have a infinite `retainCount` of your test variable. You can use this to avoid crash but this is not preferable because as I told this have a infinite `retaiCount` you can't release it and free your memory after use. So earlier methods are more correct.

This is true with all of your autorelease objects which are created with class methods and not with `init`.

Hope this will clear you more.

Comment: can i release the object in the dealloc method.

Comment: Yes you can release it in dealloc method. But you have to do it in `viewDidUnload` as you are assigning memory in `viewDidLoad`. But make sure that after `viewDidUnload` called you don't have to access this variable by any way, not even using delegate methods. Otherwise you will get crash because of object got released. :)

Comment: thanks kapil, mehul's answer fixes me and ur answer gives more info to me once again thanks kapil.

Comment: Note that static strings (and similar objects) won't have an infinite retain count.  The returned retain count is -1, but it is entirely an implementation detail akin to the recommended (but silly) singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think **simple allocation** will solve the problem. Just replace this code in the viewDidLoad method

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

test=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Sample"];
```

}

Comment: @mehul's answer fixes me thanks user_aj i will try urs also and replay u.